# (Verbs) To arrive ~ Touchaku suru vs Tsuku vs Todoku

Tags: meaning

Good day to everyone,

I am a student here in Japan studying 日本語 and I was watching a few videos of Japanese lessons and noticed that there are a lot of verbs that have the same meaning. For example, `Touchaku suru`, `Tsuku` and `Todoku` all mean "to arrive". Are there any instances wherein one is used more than the other? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is based mostly on my own experience.

着く{つく} is the most commonly used verb for "arrive", as in "I've arrived at the station".

届く{とどく} tends to be used for things or abstract concepts.  For example, on instant messenger, if you send a message and you want to check if the other person got the message because you didn't get a response, you would use 届く.  You can also use it for feelings; it is commonly used for love, e.g. 私の気持ちが届いたでしょう, which can be properly translated as "I wonder if my feelings arrived?", but more loosely as "I wonder if you understood my feelings (i.e. I love you, etc)".

到着する{とうちゃくする} tends to be used for long distances and/or for long-distance modes of transportation, and especially most commonly for airplanes.  For example, when your airplane lands, you may send a text message to your friends/family saying 到着した.

Comment: I gave you a +1 but would like to add that 到着する does not need to be a long distance trip. It may be used in short trips as well. For example: 渋谷駅を12:00に出発して、新宿駅には12:07に到着する予定です。

Comment: It just means "to arrive at a destination". (Source) https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156378/meaning/m0u/

Comment: Hmm sorry I had to google translate because I've just been studying for around 1 month right now. So `touchaku suru` is like a bit formal i guess? and `Tsuku` is for something like "hey i just arrived here in Japan", and `Todoku` is for things like "The letter arrived!". Am I correct to assume this?

Comment: Also, much thanks. This site is really full of helpful people. :)

Comment: @DXV Having walked it personally, I can confirm that Shibuya station to Shinjuku station is quite far, even though it's only a couple minutes by train ;-)

Comment: @Ertai87 It’s just an example. I know how far apart they are.  :)

Answer (score 4):

**着く** is the most basic word you use when something arrives at a location.

**到着する** has nothing different with 着く except it is a Sino-Japanese word that sounds slightly more formal. Besides, it is easily turned into a noun 到着 "arrival" which 着く is normally not able.

**届く** is literally closer to "reach", but more specifically telling that something is at the location to be passed to somebody. A train stops at a station doesn't mean the station obtains the train, so you can't say 届く. Also not for people unless you're committing human trafficking.

> 飛行機が空港に着く = 飛行機が空港に到着する *the plane arrives at the airport*
>
> 飛行機が空港に届く *the plane is delivered to the airport*